# When is $S^G [G] \cong S$ as a $S^G[G]$-module?

Tags: galois-theory, invariant-theory

Let $S$ be a ring and take a finite group $G$ acting on  $S$. Put $R = S^G$, the fixed subring. When is $S$ a free rank-$1$ $R[G]$-module? That is, when do we have $S \cong R[G]$ as $R[G]$-modules?

I am sure this is known, and I am aware of the normal basis theorem for the case of fields, but this is more general. I am interested in a complete characterization of when this proeprty holds, or any partial results that do not merely apply to fields.

For one example, I conjecture that this holds for integrally closed domains. For an extension of number fields $\mathcal{O}_L / \mathcal{O}_K$ with $L/K$ Galois, I would suspect this to follow from the normal basis theorem.

Edit: my guess here was shown to be false in the comments.

Does anyone know any cool results on the matter more general than the normal basis theorem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Ergebnisse-Mathematik-Grenzgebiete-Mathematics/dp/3540119205

Comment: Presumably $G$ acts by ring automorphisms :-)

Comment: Equally trivially, you probably want $G$ to act faithfully, i.e. only $1_G$ acts via  $id_S$.

Comment: Can you realize $\Bbb{Z}[i]\simeq_{C_2}\Bbb{Z}[C_2]$ with the non-trivial element of $C_2$ acting by compex conjugation? If $\{a+bi,a-bi\}$ is a normal basis consisting of algebraic integers (so $ab\neq0$), then their $\Bbb{Z}$-span is of an even index $2ab$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. In other words, it cannot be all of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Well, $g^{-1}$ acts as the inverse of $g$, so it would act by automorphisms. But good point that we would want a faithful action.

Comment: I wanted to emphasize that the action is by *ring* automorphisms as opposed to *group* automorphisms. For example, we have $C_2$ acting on $\Bbb{Z}$, where the generator acts by negating everything. The set of fixed points then consists of zero alone, which is no good. Sorry about the level of pedantry :-) Anyway, I still don't see a way of writing $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ as $\Bbb{Z}[C_2]$ if the generator is to act via complex conjugation.

Comment: Oh interesting, so any normal basis would have to consist of a complex conjugate pair, and no such nontrivial pairs generate an index $1$ submodule.

Comment: According to the link Lord Shark the Unknown provided it's not always true for number rings. Which is something you just pointed out implicitly.